# Create a link based on what the user selects from this jQuery UI selectable drop box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

I'm using this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#method-option

This is my code:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <?php foreach ($collection as $key=> $word): ?>
    <li class="ui-widget-content"> <?php echo $word ?> </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

How do I get a hyperlink created based on what the user selects? All the words are different each time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`selected`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selected) event:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.selected.innerHTML);
        }
    });
});​
```

`ui.selected` is the DOM element of the selected item

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vf3W4/)

if you add a `data` attribute to the `li` with more details for the `href` it would be easier:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <?php foreach ($collection as $key=> $word): ?>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" data-href="<?php echo $href ?>"> <?php echo $word ?> </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

then

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            alert($(ui.selected).data('href'));
        }
    });
});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/vf3W4/1/)

To create links (anchors) using the selected item you could do something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            $item = $(ui.selected);
            $href = $item.data('href');
            $text = $item.text();

            $('<a />').attr({
                href: $href
            }).text($text).append('<br />').appendTo('#links');
        }
    });
});​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/vf3W4/2/)

### Update

You could do something like this to store the selected item until its needed - ie a button is pressed :

```
// create temp variable to store the selected element
var selected;

$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
           selected = ui.selected;
        }

    });

    $('#getSel').click(function() {
        // do what you want with the Element here
        alert(selected.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/vf3W4/4/)

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to have just one submit link? Then when it is pressed, it will generate a URL based on the selections?

Comment: @flux of course - just store the selected value somewhere (hidden input for example) and then generate the URL when the submit button is pressed using that store

Comment: Can't get it to work correctly. Don't know any jquery. Should I be building off your 3rd example? How can I store the variable without it being overwritten? Thanks.